# Exception using WebClient calling HTTPS URLs

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, webclient

For about 3 months I have a public app which is using the WebClient to call some HTTPS API.
Until about 3 weeks ago everything worked fine, but suddenly the app stopped working and all the WebClient calls throw "The remote server returned an error: NotFound." exception.

I didn't update my app in any way, the API didn't change, I didn't notice any update for the Windows Phone.
I mention that my app is targeting the Windows Phone OS 7.1 and I also tried to use the HttpWebRequest class - the result is the same.
My code looks something like this:

```
private void tile_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e) 
    { 
        WebClient wc = new WebClient(); 
        wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);             

        wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("https://www.google.com"));  
    } 

    void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        try { 
            StreamReader s = new StreamReader(e.Result); 
            string r = s.ReadToEnd(); 
            MessageBox.Show(r); 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
        } 
    }
```

This code will fail every time it's called with the above mentioned exception. If I would try to get the "http://www.google.com" or any other HTTP URL the code will work fine.
However, I need to use HTTPS as I need to send also credentials with the WebClient calls.

I found on the Internet that other people ran into such issues last year, but this problem was supposed to be fixed with Mango update.

Does anybody know how can I fix this issue or any workaround as I ran out of ideas.

Thank you in advance!

Regards,
Andrei

Answer (score 0):

First the NotFound error is a generic one, to get the specifics of the problem you need to use a tool like Fiddler (with the emulator: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2010/10/15/fiddler-and-the-windows-phone-emulator.aspx / with a device : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/01/09/debugging-windows-phone-7-device-traffic-with-fiddler.aspx)

Now maybe it's a problem with the SSL certificate? I you visit the same URL with a desktop browser do you get a warning/error about its validity? If so you are out of luck, because I don't think you can override the validation of the certificate on Windows Phone like it's possible with the fwk on desktop.

But first try to debug with Fiddler to get some details.

Comment: I user Fiddler (Wireshark as well) already and what I noticed it that a connection is established, but the actual request is not sent from the device. This is very weird as the same code worked fine for about 2 months and suddenly it stopped working (for me and other users of my app) - this without any changes.

Comment: Did you install the Fiddler SSL certificate?  The request you see is the HTTP handsake not the actual HTTPS request. On the device/emulator, open the browser and visite http://computername:8888/ and click on the link "install the certificate". After that you should be able to get te details.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in my reply. I installed the Fiddler certificate on the emulator and the calls to https://google.com started working. However, the calls to the Delicious API I do in my public app still fail with the same message...

Comment: And in the Fiddler you don't see more details about the error?

Comment: have you found any solution to this problem  @AndreiC i am stuck with same problem ....  please provide any help if you can